# How can I dynamically allocate a matrix?

Tags: matrix

I am trying to allocate the following matrix in Mathematica.

[image: Matrix a]

It has 1s where i=j, -1/2 in i-1,j and i+1,j. This is the code I am using to try to achieve this:

```
mat = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
  For[j = 1, i <= 10, i++,
   If[i == j, (mat[[i, j]] = 1;
     mat[[i + 1, j]] = -1/2;
     If[i > 1, mat[[i - 1, j]] = 1/2, 0]
     ), mat[[i, j]] = 0
    ]]];
```

However the output is not the desired:

[image: Output]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I need to do this for matrices of size 10x10, 50x50 and 100x100 so there is no way I am doing this by hand but I haven't been able to figure this out by my self.

Thank you.

Comment: A somewhat esoteric way: ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, Range@12, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]["DifferentiationMatrix"][[2 ;; 11, 2 ;; 11]]/-2 // Normal // MatrixForm``

Comment: Esoteric indeed.

Comment: The reason your code did not work as expected is that you used `i` in the condition of the second `For`-loop instead of 'j': `j = 1, i <= 10, i++`, where it should be `j = 1, j <= 10, j++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of many ways:

```
mat = Normal@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1/2, 
     Band[{2, 1}] -> -1/2}, {10, 10}];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `Normal@` is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'l dig into the docs to see exactly how this works. This is so much better than using the for loops to fill the array.

Comment: @ÁngelCáceresLicona You're welcome! Other ways: **(1)** ``mat = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] <= 1 :> (2 - 3 Abs[i - j])/2, {10, 10}]`` **(2)** `ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[10], {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> -1/2]` **(3)** `mat = IdentityMatrix[10] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-1/2, 9], 1] +
   DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-1/2, 9], -1]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, n]] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[-1/2, n - 1], 1, n] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[-1/2, n - 1], -1, n];

A[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]